# Terraform to enable RDS Performance Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-kms

I enabled performance insights from the console manually, which created the KMS key. Later when I ran terraform, it gives me this error, which is understandable -- it cannot replace the existing KMS key

```
InvalidParameterCombination: You can't change your Performance Insights KMS key. status code: 400
```

However, after I disabled performance insights from the RDS console, and re-run the terraform, the error persists. My expectation was that it will now create a new KMS key, thus there shouldn't be any need to "change" the KMS key. Why does the error persist?

PS: I tried `terraform import` as well, but it didn't work either.

Edit:
This is the TF code:

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "db" {
  # This has been in the config before
  kms_key_id        = module.kms.kms_key_arn
  ...
  # These are new code to enable performance insights from terraform
  performance_insights_enabled = var.performance_insights_enabled
  performance_insights_kms_key_id = var.performance_insights_enabled ? module.kms.kms_key_arn : ""
  ...
}
```

PS: the KMS key, as the comment says above, has been there under "Customer Managed Keys" with the rds instance before this change. As I enabled performance insights from the console, AWS created a new KMS key under "AWS Managed Keys". After I disabled performance insights, the key is still there and I am concerned about how to deal with it (recommendation is to not delete the key but I believe it's no longer being used now).

My expectation is that after disabling performance insights, the terraform, with the new code, can link the existing customer-managed KMS key to performance insights.

Comment: What is your TF code? What do you change in it that results in the error?

Comment: @Marcin The post is updated. Can you check again and let me know if you have any other questions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe console is not doing as it should be. Please try with CLI: aws rds modify-db-instance
--db-instance-identifier sample-db-instance
--no-enable-performance-insights

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).